Excel cell formulas created by openxml evaluate multiple arguments as one and gives the value #null! to the unified argument
I create an xml document with openxml and I am adding some cells as formulas
For all the created formula cells the problem is that if they call a function, they evaluate the arguments as one and that causes #### result in the cell
For example in vba modules I have this function
Function Function1(param1, param2, param3, param4)
   ...
End Function

And in the formula that is created by openxml
=@Function1(F14 CE14 M14 CG14)

but clicking show calculation steps I see that the 4 arguments are evaluated as one
@Function1(#NULL!)

and that causes #### result
Any idea about that?

Shouldn't the function created by openxml have commas? (i.e. =@Function1(F14, CE14, M14, CG14) instead of =@Function1(F14 CE14 M14 CG14)

My list separator in region settings is space character. So in excel the argument separator is space too.
But for some reason openxml needs to produce =@Function1(F14, CE14, M14, CG14) and converts it to =@Function1(F14 CE14 M14 CG14) in excel.
And this works.
